# Unable to obtain table lock - another Flyway instance may be running

Tags: spring-boot, flyway, cockroachdb

I'm using integration of Spring Boot and Flyway (6.5.5) to run updates for CockroachDB cluster. When several instances of service are starting in the same time, all of them are trying to lock `flyway_schema_history` table to validate migrations. However, the following exception occurs:

```
2020-09-09 00:00:00.013 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               :
Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: 
Unable to obtain table lock - another Flyway instance may be running
```

I could not find any config property to tweak this. Maybe someone faced with the same issue and solved it somehow?

Workaround: restart service.

Comment: Are you trying to migrate from multiple services at the same time? Or just info?

Comment: When Application Context is being initialised, Flyway bean checked migrations and applied that's are necessary. Services are being deployed simultaneously, so yes, all of them trying to apply migrations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After debugging the issue, it's appeared in very weird Flyway behaviour:
org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.cockroachdb.CockroachDBTable

```
CockroachDB-specific table.
Note that CockroachDB doesn't support table locks. We therefore use a row in the schema history as a lock indicator;
if another process ahs inserted such a row we wait (potentially indefinitely) for it to be removed before
carrying out a migration.
*/
```

So, in my case during applying migration, service was restarted and this pseudo lock record left forever.

Workaround was delete the "lock" manually:

```
  installed_rank |             version              |               description                | type |                      script                      |  checksum   |    installed_by    |           installed_on           | execution_time | success
-----------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+----------------+----------
            -100 | d9ab17626a4d66a4d8a89fe9bdca98e9 | flyway-lock                              |      |                                                  |           0 |                    | 2020-09-14 11:25:02.874838+00:00 |              0 |  true
```

Hope, it will help someone.

The appropriate ticket has been created: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2932